# How to retrieve data only if user stay more than one second on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In an AngularJS app, users can navigate through several pages.
Each time a page is displayed, the controller fetches the server to retrieve some data.

I would like to wait 1 second before launching the request, so we do not load data if the user has quickly left the page for another view.

I tried  to use $timeout but the query is executed even if an other view and an other controller have been loaded.

```
app.controller('showController', function($scope, $routeParams, $timeout){
  $timeout(function(){
    Service.getDataDetails(id).then(function (result) {
      $scope.data = result;
    });
  },1000);
});
```

I also tried to cancel the query. The query is well canceled in the navigator, but the server still execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cancel your `$timeout` in the destructor of your controller:

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function handler() {
    $timeout.cancel(promise);
});
```

It is called when the controller is not used anymore.

---

Patrick Evens reminded me of telling you where the promise variable comes from:

```
var promise = $timeout(function(){
    Service.getDataDetails(id).then(function (result) {
        $scope.data = result;
    });
},1000);
```

Comment: You should probably include where to get the `promise` variable from :)

Comment: learn something new every day. I was concocting a `rootscope/routchangestart` solution but this is far simpler

Comment: Perfect and complete answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The $timeout service has a [***cancel method***](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout#cancel) to cancel a timeout

```
var promise = $timeout(function(){
  Service.getDataDetails(id).then(function (result) {
    $scope.data = result;
  });
},1000);
//...
//somewhere else
$timeout.cancel(promise);
```

The cancel method will cause the promise to be rejected instead of resolved.

Answer (score 0):

when you make a request, control goes to server and then in response only you get a view. So in document ready you can have timeout, this will not prevent server call. To prevent server call you need to write code in controller to wait for 1second before sending response.
I hope this might clear.

Comment: OP hasn't made a request call yet, that is what the timeout is doing waiting to make a request. They simply need to cancel their timeout to stop the request from being made.

Comment: i don't know about angular js but in a general sense I answered the question. But, anyway thanx

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling the timeout should work if it haven't fired the call to the server.

```
var timer = $timeout(function(){
    Service.getDataDetails(id).then(function (result) {
      $scope.data = result;
    });
},1000);
```

and cancelling the timeout like this:

```
$timeout.cancel(timer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the `$timeout` id by assigning it to a variable like so: `var timeoutID = $timeout(...`.

Right before the `$timeout` block, within the same scope, clear the timeout with `$timeout.cancel( timeoutID )`. This ensures that the code within the `$timeout` block will not be executed if a user navigates to a new page within the the 1000ms.

Comment: I don't think you thought this through enough. It doesn't solve the problem